# Not able to get custom jquery plugin to work

Tags: jquery

I wanted to create jquery plugin & started off creating a sample jquery plugin...But

```
$(this).css('color','blue');        
alert(this.id);
```

doesn't work...

### jquery.myPlugin.js

```
jQuery.fn.changeTextColor = function() {
alert("xx");    //this works

return this.each(function() {
    $(this).css('color','blue');        
    alert(this.id);         //both the 2 statements don't work..
});
};
```

### HTML

```
<script type = "text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript" src="jquery.myPlugin.js"></script>

<script>
$('#mypara').changeTextColor();     
</script>

</head>
<body>
<p id="mypara">dsfdsfdsf</p>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thar she blows!

```
(function( $ ) {
    $.fn.changeTextColor = function() {
        alert("xx");    //this works

        return this.each(function() {
            $(this).css('color','blue');        
            alert(this.id);
        });
    }
}(jQuery));
```

Then call with:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#mypara').changeTextColor();
});
```

Have a fiddle ;)
http://jsfiddle.net/nmkeD/

Answer (score 1):

Your script runs before `#mypara` has been parsed by the page. As such your selector cant find it. Try doing it on document ready event by doing this:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('#mypara').changeTextColor();     
    });
</script>
```

where `$(function() { ... });` is shorthand for "When the document is fully loaded run me"